# Symmetric matrix are diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a question somewhere

> Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix with real entries such that $M^k$= 0 for some $k∈N$. Show that $M = 0$.

As I just finished reading self-adjoint operators, so can I directly use the fact that linear map with matrix $M$ has a basis with eigenvectors with enough eigenvalues and hence all the eigenvalues must be $0$.

Is this approach correct or wrong?

Comment: It is a good approach.  Did you have difficulty finishing off the argument?

Comment: No actually my concern is while dealing with self-adjoint operators we assume vector space to be a "inner product space", which is not mentioned in question.

Comment: The usual dot product in $\mathbb R^n$ is an inner product.

Comment: @Shady I wouldn't worry too much about the inner product space thing. It's a generalisation of $\Bbb{R}^n$ equipped with the dot product (or $\Bbb{C}^n$ equipped with its version of the dot product). Where you read "self-adjoint operator", you can replace it with "symmetric (or, Hermitian) matrix". Symmetric (Hermitian) matrices are always diagonalisable, which gives you the result you need.

Comment: Thanks @Theo, one more thing when working in $C^n$ can I again directly use this property for normal operators?

Comment: @Shady If I understand you correctly, yes you can. A matrix is normal if it commutes with its conjugate transpose, and normal matrices are diagonalisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this approach seems correct. I'm just putting the answer below for the sake of completeness.

We just use what you said and the fact that an eigenvector of $M$ is an eigenvector of $M^{k}$. Say $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\}$ forms a basis of eigenvectors of $M$, each having an eigenvalue of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots \lambda_n$. Then the same vectors form a basis of eigenvectors of $M^{k}$ but with the eigenvalues $\lambda_1^k, \lambda_2^{k}, \ldots \lambda_n^{k}$. Since $M^k$ is $0$ we conclude all of $\lambda_i=0$ and so $M$ must be $0$ as it maps $\text{span}\{v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\} = \mathbb{R}^n$ to $0$.